# Find sequence of consecutive numbers which's multiple is N

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I have an exercise with an input `N` and it wants me to find a sequence of consecutive numbers which's multiple is equal to `N`.  Example

```
Input | Output
  60   | 3 5
```

3*4*5=60

What i have tried

```
cin>>b;
for (int i = 2; i <=b; ++i)
{
    c=1;
    for (int j = i; j <=b; ++j)
    {
        c*=j;
        if(c==b){
            cout<<i<<" "<<j<<endl;
            return 0;
        }else if(c>b){
            j=b;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should name your variables better. `c`, `b`, `i`, and `j` are very vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution in Python (see end of the post for C++ version):

```python
def seq_with_product(n):
    """Return a sequence of consecutive numbers whose product is n."""
    i, curr_prod = 1, 1
    max_j = int(n**0.5) + 1 # n**0.5 is square root of n
    for j in range(2, max_j + 1):
        curr_prod *= j
        while curr_prod > n and i < j-1:
            curr_prod /= i
            i += 1
        if curr_prod == n:
            return range(i, j+1)
    return []
```

Let *i* and *j* be the start and end number in the current sequence. You start from the sequence with the smallest product `[1, 2]`, and check if it is smaller than the given target `n`. If it is, you want to increase the product, so you include the next number by increasing *j*. As soon as you get to a product which is larger, you start removing numbers from the product, starting from the smallest (the `while` loop). If you get the exact product, your answer are the numbers between *i* and *j*. So for example, this is how you reach the answer to 60:

```
[1, 2]          # too small, include the next number
[1, 2, 3]       # too small, include the next number
[1, 2, 3, 4]    # too small, include the next number
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] # too big, remove the first number
[2, 3, 4, 5]    # too big, remove the first number
[3, 4, 5]       # found
```

Note that you don't need to consider numbers greater than the square root of the target number plus one, so you can stop at `max_j`.

In C++, it would be something like:

```c++
int i = 1, curr_prod = 1;
int max_j = sqrt(n) + 1;
for (int j = 2; j <= max_j; j++) {
  curr_prod *= j;
  while (curr_prod > n && i < j - 1) {
    curr_prod /= i;
    i += 1;
  }
  if (curr_prod == n) cout << i << " " << j << endl;
}
```

Comment: I need two numbers.First and last values from array

Comment: @user7302801  Then you can just return or print `i` and `j`.

Comment: Sorry,but i know python not.Can ye change thy code?

Comment: This is a good solution (+1), but since it (intentionally) doesn't consider all possible ranges, the answer might benefit from a sentence or two explaining how you know that it never skips over a correct solution. Also, I think the `return []` should instead be `return [n, n]`.

Comment: The start number of the sequence must be a factor of the number, though not necessarily a prime factor.  The number itself is also a possible start for a sequence of length 1.  You might be able to save time by only considering sequences starting with a factor of the number.

Comment: @user7302801 Added version in C++.

Comment: @rossum This is a very useful observation. We are essentially looking for consecutive factors of `n`. I will probably write another solution based on that.

Answer (score 1):

Because of this assignment, the inner loop will never terminate if no sequence with the given starting value `i` is found:

```
else if (c > b) {
    j = b;
}
```

Instead you should do this:

```
else if (c > b) {
    break;
}
```

This will terminate the inner loop and check for a sequence with the next start value `i+1`.

You should also consider the (very common) case that the only sequence contains only one element which is the number `N` itself.

Comment: Unfortunately it gives the same result.Perhaps problems is numbers maybe too big?

Comment: @user7302801: Are `c` and `b` declared as `int`? How large are your numbers?